# Efficiently create bins that are greater than or equal to lower value and strictly less than higher value in R

Tags: r, loops, split

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
outcome  treatment
2        0.01
3        0.78
2        0.54
1        0.68
4        0.97
5        0.40
2        0.25
```

I would like to split the treatment variable into 4 evenly spaced bins. Assuming the treatment variable spans from 0 to 1, I would like the bins to be:

```
Bin 1: [0,0.25)
Bin 2: [0.25, 0.5)
Bin 3: [0.5, 0.75)
Bin 4: [0.75, 1.0)
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
outcome  treatment  bin 
2        0.01       1
3        0.78       3
2        0.54       3
1        0.68       3
4        0.97       4
5        0.40       2
2        0.25       2
```

I tried using the following:

```
split(df, cut(df$treatment, 4))
```

This didn't work because the bin outputs looked like (0,0.25] rather than [0, 0.25), and I didn't know how to change it.

I am open to any way of doing this, but I am most familiar with the tidyverse.

Comment: Does this work for you `as.integer(cut(df1$treatment, breaks = seq(0, 1, .25), right = FALSE))` ?

Comment: @markus  Why did you include as.integer()?

Comment: And how do I make this output into a column in the original dataframe?

Comment: `as.integer` because `cut` returns a factor, assignment via `df1$new_col <- ...`